# Парсинг xml с помощью Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Есть задача и ее надо строго выполнить с помощью **Jackson** для **Java**. 
Имеется `List<>` содержащий объекты, которые имеют свои поля. Имя, id. Нужно с помощью библиотеки **Jackson** запарсить все объекты коллекции в `xml` и потом распарсить обратно. Временное хранилище такое. На просторах интернета находил примеры для `.json` файлов. Как понимаю, мы создаем `ObjectManager` и дальше форичем делаем так :

```
for (Contact contact : dataStorage.getContacts()) {
    mapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "temp.json"), contact);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(contact));
}
```

Как можно поменять такой код для парсинга в `xml` файл? Использовал вот такой артефакт `jackson-mapper-asl` для **maven**. Вероятно, что понадобится что-то другое.

Answer (score 1):

> Имеется List<> содержащий объекты, которые имеют свои поля. Имя, id

Смею предположить, что класс, описывающий этот обьект имеет вид:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="users") // <- добавляем аннотацию
public class User {

    private String name;

    private String id;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Затем маппим его с помощью `XmlMapper` от `Jackson`

Конвертируем Objects -> Xml

```
List<Users> users = loadUsers();

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(users);
```

Обратно:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
Groups groups = mapper.readValue(xml, new TypeReference<List<User>>());
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на мысль. Первое, что нужно было сменить - это артефакт, как и предполагал, на вод такой jackson-dataformat-xml. И в файл все записалось. Обратно же читается только 1й элемент для конструкции list..add(mapper.readValue(fileInputStream, Contact.class)); Если написать:
        int bytes=inputStream.read();
            if(bytes > 0) {
                list..add(mapper.readValue(fileInputStream, Contact.class));
            }
Выдает IOException
В вашем примере new TypeReference<List<User>>() - это что?

Comment: [new TypeReference<List<User>>()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) - из-за стирания (type erasure) у нас потеряется тип. Мы не можем указать там `mapper.readValue(xml, List<User>.class)`